# Using Dynamic Data-Model For $scope in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want to do something like this:

```
function doSometing(array, dynamicID){
     $scope.property1_dynamicID = SomeFunction();
     $scope.property2_dynamicID = OtherFunction();
}
```

what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var propertyName = 'property1_' + dynamicID;
$scope[propertyName] = someFunction();
```